# Is this definition of a complete bipartite graph correct?

Tags: graph-theory

The book I am using defined a complete graph $K_{m,n} = \overline{K}_m + \overline{K}_n$. Is this correct? I am confused since the complement of a complete graph is an empty graph. How is the addition of two empty graph a complete bipartite graph if we follow the definition?

Comment: What is the definition of addition of two graphs?

Comment: It didn't say any definition of Km and Kn in conjunction with the given definition of Km,n above.

Comment: although earlier in the reading, it defined Km as a complete graph with m points similarly for Kn

Comment: I know what $K_m$ is. I'm wondering what the definition of $+$ is.

Comment: it means join Km and Kn

Comment: What does complete bipartite graph mean to you, and how are you having trouble connecting this to the join of two graphs with no edges?

Comment: a complete bipartite graph has two sets of vertices wherein each vertex of one set connect to every vertex of the other set.

Comment: And, perhaps more importantly, the are no edges internally in any of the two sets. Which means that each of them is the complement of a complete graph.

Comment: got it. thanks Arthur!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some authors use $G+H$ to indicate the *graph join*, which is a copy of $G$ and a copy of $H$ together with every edge between $G$ and $H$. This is IMO unfortunate, since $+$ makes more sense as disjoint union. (Authors who use $+$ for join probably use either $G\cup H$ or $G\sqcup H$ for the disjoint union.)

Comment: if given that G and H are disjoint. G + H would mean G∪H plus the edges that connect each vertex in G to every vertex in H, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it. In fact $\overline G\text{ join }\overline H$ is the same thing as $\overline{G\sqcup H}$, so the definition in your question is equivalent to $\overline{K_m\sqcup K_n}$.

Comment: yes it makes more sense that way! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like in your book the notation $G_1 + G_2$ refers to the graph obtained as follows: take the graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ and join each vertex in $G_1$ to each vertex in $G_2$.

Thus, if we take the empty graph on $m$ vertices $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ and the empty graph on $n$ vertices $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ and join each $x_i$ to each $y_j$, we get the graph $K_{m,n}$.